# How to get a Total of Last Five Values In Sqlite?

Tags: sqlite

In my Database,

There is Data like this,

```
 ID  average_time
 1    5
 2    10
 3    15
 4    20
 5    25 
 6    30
```

I create a query;

```
 select total(average_time) from tbl_Timer order by id desc limit 5
```

It"s give the total of all values.

I want Total of LastFive Data,

How can i Do that?

Comment: You could try sum() instead total()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
select  sum(avtime) from
  (SELECT average_time AS avTime 
   FROM tbl_Timer
   ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

If ID is sequential how about something like this

```
select sum(average_time) from data where id >= (select max(id)-4 from data);
```